# What SFX packs would you like to see sold?

Tags: untagged

Hey everyone!

I am in the process of recording and designing more content for my sound effect website and I would like to know what the public looks for when purchasing sounds.  The website is www.getsoundeffects.com  (The site is still in a soft launch beta state, so some of my content is not listed yet).

Having said that, I would like to hear some requests of what people would like to see in a SFX pack.

What things do you really like to see, or look for when purchasing a SFX pack?

What SFX would you like to see more of?

What SFX have you always wanted to purchase but can never seem to find the sound pack anywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sounds I've never heard before

Comment: Second that :-)


Comment: @tim Wiseguy, are we? ;)

Comment: At first I was not sure about this reply, but after thinking it over it had me thinking outside the box, literally..  I am going to record some things using really odd techniques.  So Tim might be a wise guy, but hes a smart wise guy because it has indeed inspired me to get even more creative with my recordings.

Thanks!

Comment: @Stavrosound I was being deadly serious! The most interesting aspect of any one persons contribution is that thing which is unique to them. So me saying 'I need the sound of XYZ' contributes nothing & means that person is no closer to realising their true worth - find some sounds I have never heard yet, that only you could find!!